# Parse XML trovit feed with PHP

Tags: xml, simplexml

I would like to parse a specific XML feed, but I am getting empty value using SIMPLEXML

Any help will be really appreciated.

This an example of the Trovit XML feed.

I for example, use the below file like this:

$xml = simplexml_load_file('myfile.xml');
print_r($xml);

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<trovit>
<ad>
    <id><![CDATA[7004578]]></id>
    <url><![CDATA[http://www.yourdomain.co.uk/ad/7004578]]></url>
    <title><![CDATA[2008 Toyota Prius Hybrid]]></title>
    <content><![CDATA[111 Cruise control, Climate control, Front passenger airbag and
side airbags, Front and rear head airbags, Anti-lock brakes, Traction control, Remote central
door locking, Remote control alarm, Immobiliser, Front and rear electric windows, 16" alloy
wheels, Front fog lights, Radio cassette and CD autochanger, Steering wheel mounted controls,
Body coloured bumpers, Electric doormirrors.]]></content>
    <price><![CDATA[10000]]></price>
    <make><![CDATA[Toyota]]></make>
    <model><![CDATA[Prius]]></model>
    <color><![CDATA[Metallic Grey]]></color>
    <year><![CDATA[2008]]></year>
    <city><![CDATA[Bristol]]></city>
    <city_area><![CDATA[Bristol]]></city_area>
    <postcode><![CDATA[]]></postcode>
    <region><![CDATA[Bristol]]></region>
    <mileage unit="kilometers"><![CDATA[10000]]></mileage>
    <doors><![CDATA[5]]></doors>
    <fuel><![CDATA[petrol/ hybrid]]></fuel>
    <transmission><![CDATA[manual]]></transmission>
    <engine_size><![CDATA[1781]]></engine_size>
    <power><![CDATA[75]]></power>
    <seats><![CDATA[5]]></seats>
    <gears><![CDATA[6]]></gears>
    <pictures>
        <picture>
          <picture_url><![CDATA[http://www.yourdomain.co.uk/image1.jpg]]></picture_url>
          <picture_title><![CDATA[front]]></picture_title>
        </picture>
        <picture>
          <picture_url><![CDATA[http://www.yourdomain.co.uk/image2.jpg]]></picture_url>
          <picture_title><![CDATA[interior]]></picture_title>
        </picture>
    </pictures>
    <date><![CDATA[20/01/2011 14:30]]></date>
    <is_new><![CDATA[0]]></is_new>
    <car_type><![CDATA[hatchback]]></car_type>
    <warranty><![CDATA[until 2011]]></warranty>
</ad>

<ad>
    <id><![CDATA[7004579]]></id>
    <url><![CDATA[http://www.yourdomain.co.uk/ad/7004578]]></url>
    <title><![CDATA[2008 Toyota Prius Hybrid]]></title>
    <content><![CDATA[222 Cruise control, Climate control, Front passenger airbag and
side airbags, Front and rear head airbags, Anti-lock brakes, Traction control, Remote central
door locking, Remote control alarm, Immobiliser, Front and rear electric windows, 16" alloy
wheels, Front fog lights, Radio cassette and CD autochanger, Steering wheel mounted controls,
Body coloured bumpers, Electric doormirrors.]]></content>
    <price><![CDATA[210000]]></price>
    <make><![CDATA[Toyota]]></make>
    <model><![CDATA[Prius]]></model>
    <color><![CDATA[Metallic Grey]]></color>
    <year><![CDATA[2008]]></year>
    <city><![CDATA[Bristol]]></city>
    <city_area><![CDATA[Bristol]]></city_area>
    <postcode><![CDATA[]]></postcode>
    <region><![CDATA[Bristol]]></region>
    <mileage unit="kilometers"><![CDATA[10000]]></mileage>
    <doors><![CDATA[5]]></doors>
    <fuel><![CDATA[petrol/ hybrid]]></fuel>
    <transmission><![CDATA[manual]]></transmission>
    <engine_size><![CDATA[1781]]></engine_size>
    <power><![CDATA[75]]></power>
    <seats><![CDATA[5]]></seats>
    <gears><![CDATA[6]]></gears>
    <pictures>
        <picture>
          <picture_url><![CDATA[http://www.yourdomain.co.uk/image1.jpg]]></picture_url>
          <picture_title><![CDATA[front]]></picture_title>
        </picture>
        <picture>
          <picture_url><![CDATA[http://www.yourdomain.co.uk/image2.jpg]]></picture_url>
          <picture_title><![CDATA[interior]]></picture_title>
        </picture>
    </pictures>
    <date><![CDATA[20/01/2011 14:30]]></date>
    <is_new><![CDATA[0]]></is_new>
    <car_type><![CDATA[hatchback]]></car_type>
    <warranty><![CDATA[until 2011]]></warranty>
</ad>
</trovit>
```

Comment: Hi All   Any help on this please?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? (Try with `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`) The XML itself seems valid - see here for code successfully parsing it: http://codepad.viper-7.com/0tvKUT

Comment: Hi.  No I am not getting any error. I am only getting empty values. Not really sure why?

Comment: Well, like I say, the XML parses fine, so without any error message, there's not a lot of information to go on here. You could check [`libxml_use_internal_errors`](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) as well. Also, if you use `var_dump` or `var_export` rather than `print_r`, you'll see whether your "empty" result is NULL, an empty array, etc.

Comment: Here's a [working example with your XML and SimpleXMLElement](http://codepad.org/HVJBY9iI).

Comment: Can you give me the link of Trovit XML feed ?